# Android native email client doesn't fetch files from location Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()

Tags: android, email-attachments, email-client

I have an android application for which i have an option to send the logs via email

For this i am using the following procedure

```
String outputPath=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ File.separator+"sundeeplogs"+ File.separator;    

        File dir = new File (outputPath); 
        if (!dir.exists())
        {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        File zipFileSDCard = new File(outputPath+"sundeep_logs.zip");
```

Now i would copy a zip which is in secure location to the zipFileSDCard .

I have checked that the file has been successfully copied

adding the zip file to the intent

```
targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(zipFileSDCard));
```

when i send an email using gmail app then the email is sent with the attachments and i can view the attachment in the received email.

problem:

when i use Android native email client it won't attach the file sometimes even if it attaches and the email is sent there is no attachment in the received email.

Finally i found the problem why attachment is missing but could not find the reason why native client is discarding the attachment. the problem explained in this link [Unloaded attachment isn't marked for download error in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555575/unloaded-attachment-isnt-marked-for-download-error-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

What os version are you using? on older devices i've found that this just doesn't work with gmail client app.

Comment: i have tested on all the OS version's and i am facing this issue on all of them, native client is dropping the attachment before sending the email. It is working fine for me with gmail app on all OS versions. The problem with native client i am facing is explained in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555575/unloaded-attachment-isnt-marked-for-download-error-in-android

Comment: hmm... that doesn't sound right. i've tested (well, using internal storage) but it works just fine. do you have Android Manifest write-permission enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GMail is much more lenient than some native email application with respect to attachments.

After much analysis and trial and error, I found that the following intent will work with both GMail and the native email application on a Samsung Galaxy S5 (no guarantees for other devices)

```
public static void emailFile(Activity context, File attachmentInCacheDir, String to, String subject, String body) {
        Intent intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);//SENDTO does not seem to work for native
        intent.setData(Uri.fromParts("mailto",to, null));
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { to });
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
        intent.setType("message/email");
        if (attachmentInCacheDir != null) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://" + CachedFileProvider.getAuthority(context) + "/" + attachmentInCacheDir.getName()));
        }
        context.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"), 1000);
    }
```

As you can see, I am using a provider as the Uri so that I don't have to expose data by copying to public directory.  I am not sure if this is another requirement for all native email apps to work.  When implementing the provider, I needed to implement the 'query' method to return the file size of the attachment otherwise native app would reject it.